# Setting Realm schema version in MacOS app

Tags: swift, macos, realm

Unlike iOS, the app delegate's applicationWillFinishLaunching and applicationDidFinishLaunching are called *after* ViewDidLoad on the initial NSViewController.

Main.c (or main.swift) seems to be retired and without changing AppDelegate too much, the only place I can think of to call schemaVersion is in the ViewDidLoad of the initial view controller, which seems ugly to me.

What is recommended way to set Realm's schemaVersion in MacOS apps written in Swift?

Answer (score 3):

The init() of the MacOS AppDelegate seems to be working great.

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    override init() {
        super.init()

        let info = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!
        let version = info["RealmSchemaVersion"] as! UInt64
        Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.schemaVersion = version
    }
    ...
}
```